# How to return error message from FileResult method in asp.net MVC 4 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fileresult

I have a fileresult method in asp.net mvc4 that returns a report in an excel file. Now how can i return an error message from this method if my conditions are not met !! Since we can only return a file from this method ?! 
Thnks

Comment: You can see the answer of a similar question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20335684/asp-net-mvc-4-fileresult-in-error

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can change signature of action method to `public ActionResult MyMethod()` and return `FileResult` when `ModelState.IsValid==true` and `ViewResult` when `ModelState.IsValid==false`

Comment: thnks Kirill , Actually I already solved my problem by returning a plain text which is not a good approach . But I didnt know I could return a file from a an ActionResult . Thnks .

Comment: What about returning FileResult with some notification message to show up?